# Using HTML attribute within CMS source code

Tags: html, content-management-system, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, datakey

Im using **Prestashop** for a website where the content pages are build using:

`Prestashop > Preferences > CMS > Source-Code`.

So for each CMS page i use source code which is basic **HTML**.

**THE PROBLEM**

Im trying to integrate a widget to the site CMS page, now ive tested the widget on a simple html document and it works perfectly.

This is the code for the HTML page.

```
<div class="work-widget" data-key="1111plzwork111"></div>
```

Prestashop CMS > Source-Code throws out the `data-key="1111plzwork111"`, which obviously breaks the widget.

So After saving the Source-Code the HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="work-widget"></div>
```

**Expected:**

Can someone please help me figure out a fix for this i dont know what to do to make it work. So if i save the source code the HTML wil keep the `data-key="1111plzwork111"` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to disable the *Use HTMLPurifier Library* option in the Preferences > General menu in PrestaShop 1.6 or Shop Parameters > General in PrestaShop 1.7
[image: Use HTMLPurifier Library option]

Comment: Thanks man works!! i actually ended up using js to add the html into div, but you solved the issue!

Answer (score 1):

@WebXY has the fixed answer and it work perfectly. But in case someone is not happy with switching the *HTMLPurifier* off as it composes security risks.

**Security Risk:**

> Know thy enemy. Hackers have a huge arsenal of XSS vectors hidden within the depths of the HTML specification. HTML Purifier is effective because it decomposes the whole document into tokens and removing non-whitelisted elements, checking the well-formedness and nesting of tags, and validating all attributes according to their RFCs.

I used JavaScript to fix the problem, so i added an `div` with a `id` to the CMS source Code.

Then on a certain **URL** i found the id and added `innerHTML`:

**JS:**

```
function dinePlan() {
"use strict";

var location = window.location.pathname;
var dinePlanId = document.getElementById("dineplan");

 if (location !== null && dinePlanId !== null) {
    if (location === "/restaurant"){
        // console.log("found you");
        dinePlanId.innerHTML = '<div class="work-widget" data-key="1111plzwork111"></div>';
       } 
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  dinePlan();
}
```

**Source-Code:** (within the CMS)

```
<div id="dineplan"></div>
```

Comment: +1 I'd also use this approach. You don't want to lower security across whole shop(s) just so you can use data attribute on one element.

Comment: @TheDrot yess man i just slept better approaching this method :)